# Double preg match login validation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to validate a username login - it can only accepts letters, numbers and undescore, max 20 signs, here's my regex:

Regex: `^[\w_]{4,20}$`
[working example at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/ic79bM7nL7)

It should accept this logins:

```
login
login_login
_login
_87login
837420
login898
```

But it should return false when login consists only underscores:

```
 ________
```

How to do this in one preg? Thats my question :)

Comment: Guess indeed! Can you just tell us what the criteria for a valid username are? (Also, `[\w_]` means the same thing as `\w`.)

Comment: How many underscores are there allowed ? Plus why complicate things while there is `if(preg_match('/\w{4,20}/', $user) && !preg_match('/_{2,}/', $user)){` ?

Comment: Before you can write a regular expression, you have to be able to describe, in English, the rules that you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check that there is at least one letter/number, use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z0-9])\w{4,20}$
```

Comment: That still seems to allow multiple underscores in a row, as long as letters are included in the string too.

Comment: To quote my answer: "*If you just want to check that there is at least one letter/number*". Of course it allows multiple underscores in a row, but as the specifications are not clear, I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

`/^(_?[a-z0-9-])+$/i`

This accepts strings that consist of letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores, but does not allow `__`. Also note that this does not check the length, you would have to do that using `strlen()`. It also does not allow a trailing underscore, but your specs do not state that that is valid.